# esper - every-distinct reset subexpression?

Tags: esper

How does one reset a esper every-distinct sub expression?

I have a number of voyage reports with unique ids and I want to detect when ever they change their destination. The following detects the first change but subsequent changes are not detected.

```
 select new from pattern [every-distinct(new.id) new=VoyageReport -> (VoyageReport(id=new.id and new.destination!=destination)) where timer:within(2 hours)]
```

id=1,destination=A

id=1,destination=B

ok

id=1,destination=C

is not detected?

Answer (score 0):

Use "every" instead of "every-distinct"